# Which is the best way to check a bit array in Cuda?

Tags: cuda, bit-manipulation, bit

I need to launch N threads (in one block)

This is the code, 'e' is a bignumber on 1024b. I need to copy it on the gpu and read it bit by bit.

Host code:

```
unsigned char *__e;
BIGNUM *e = BN_new();
unsigned char exp[128];

//      e
i = cudaMalloc( (void**)&__e, 128* sizeof(unsigned char) );
if(i != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaMalloc __e FAIL! Code: %d\n", i);

BN_bn2bin128B(e, exp);   // copy data in exp

for(i=0; i<128; i++)
    exp[i] = reverse(exp[i]);

i = cudaMemcpy( __e, exp, 128* sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if(i != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaMemcpy __e FAIL! Code: %d\n", i);


unsigned char reverse(unsigned char b) {
 b = (b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4;
 b = (b & 0xCC) >> 2 | (b & 0x33) << 2;
 b = (b & 0xAA) >> 1 | (b & 0x55) << 1;
 return b;
}
```

Device code:

```
for(int i=0; i<1024; i++)
    if(ISBITSET(__e, i) == 1)
        //do something
```

Header:

```
#define ISBITSET(x,i) ((x[i>>3] & (1<<(i&7)))!=0)
```

Unfortunately ISBITSET doesnt accept anything different from __e, so I cant check the further values in __e itself

How can I solve it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: May be you should put down your initial attempts and the roadblocks you are hitting.

Comment: -1 You need to put a little bit more effort into your question than this. Your description of what you're trying to do is ambiguous and incomplete. What have you tried? What are the issues you are anticipating in a CUDA implementation? Maybe also add some pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

The GPU is a 32 bit machine, so you'll want to process your 1024 bits 32 bits at a time, not 8. So, you should replace all `unsigned char` with `unsigned int` and adjust the values accordingly.

The GPU has a fast PTX instruction for reversing 32 bits at a time, so you may want to implement that on the GPU. The instruction is called `brev`. To use it, you would add inline PTX, something like this (untested):

```
asm("brev.b32 %0, %1;" : "=r"(dst_var) : "r"(src_var));
```

For more information, see NVIDIA's document, "Using Inline PTX Assembly In CUDA".

```
for(int i=0; i<1024; i++)
    if(ISBITSET(__e, i) == 1)
        //do something
```

This code may have a performance problem. Presuming that there is a 50% chance that a bit is on, you only get 50% of the possible performance since half of your threads will have to wait while the other half perform the `//do something`. I can't think of a workaround though. You may also want to launch threads instead of looping.

> Unfortunately ISBITSET doesnt accept anything different from __e, so I cant check the further values in __e itself

Could you elaborate? The `ISBITSET` macro looks ok to me and looks like it can process any array of unsigned chars, which is what `__e` is.

Comment: For the brev, it'd be nice to have some code, but you can also simply just give me a good link regarding it. For the for cicle: can you explain better what you mean by performance problem? Because all of the threads go through it. For the error, ISBITSET was returning me an error when I was trying to compile with a &__e[i], it was complaining about a requested pointer-to-object. After many attempts I solved by adding a parenthesis... so like this: (&__e[i]) and it went..

Comment: I added an example for `brev`. About ISBITSET, seems you discovered one of the joys of preprocessor macros. The potential performance problem is not in the ISBITSET macro, but in the `if` conditional. If the `if` evaluates to `true` for half of the 32 threads in a warp, the other half of the threads, are disabled while `//do something` runs. If `//do something` takes up all of the time in the kernel, the kernel will run at only half of its potential performance.